# Simplest audio editor, for Mac OS X

Tags: osx, audio, audio-editing, audio-recording

I simply need to record an introduction to insert at the front of a recorded audio presentation. That presentation is recorded as a .m4a file, Apple MPEG-4 audio.

I just want add title info: who gave the presentation, the place, and the date. Not professional at all; don't need sound level adjustments. The less features the better.

What is the simplest possible audio editing app for a Mac user to:

- Record a brief clip of several seconds.
- Insert that clip to the front of a longer (1-2 hour) audio recording.

Is there any "QuickTime" app anymore bundled by Apple like the old days that can do this?

Does Apple still bundle a free movie/video editing app? Would that be a good way?

Any super-simple audio editing app in the App Store?

Again, needs to be quick and easy for a very-much-amateur to learn in 3 minutes how to perform this minor edit.

Comment: Have you used audacity?

Answer (score 3):

QuickTime player can do what you want.

File > New Recording

Once you're happy with it (eg re-record or trim it) save it then do

Edit > Add Clip to End and select the existing recording to be added.

Save/export as required

Further info: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201066